Easiest way to do TCP trace on Windows
I am looking for a way on Windows to do a TCP trace from my local machine, via a VPN to our remote AWS RDS database.
Since I did find satisfactory solutions on Google I was curious what Windows user do for TCP tracing to remote servers?

I wanted to point out that one can trace in Powershell, as such:
tnc [RDS host] -Port [port number]

